# Putty/Wireshark in terminal/on vps?

Tags: putty, wireshark, vps

Is there a way to use these specific programs through a terminal or on a vps? (By through a terminal, i mean with no displays, just the actual terminal). Im on RHEL/CentOS7.

Comment: Do you need to use Wireshark or are command-line equivalent tools acceptable?

Comment: I have already found a solution. tcpdump for TCP and tshark for any protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. tshark is an application similar to wireshark that works in the terminal.  Unlike tcpdump, this will capture UDP packets in a recognizable format.